# Error in implementation of Crank-Nicolson method applied to 1D TDSE?

Tags: python, simulation, physics, numerical-methods

This is more of a computational physics problem, and I've asked it on physics stack exchange, but no answers on there. This is, I suppose, a mix of the disciplines on here and there (and maybe even mathematics stack exchange), so finding the right place to post is a task in of itself apparently...

I'm attempting to use Crank-Nicolson scheme to solve the TDSE in 1D. The initial wave is a real Gaussian that has been normalised wrt its probability density. As the solution evolves, a depression grows in the central peak of the real part of the wave, and the imaginary part's central trough is perhaps a bit higher than I expect (image below).

Does this behaviour seem reasonable? I have searched around and not seen questions/figures that are similar. I've tested another person's code from Github and it exhibits the same behaviour, which makes me feel a bit better. But I still think the center peak should just decrease in height and increase in width. The likelihood of me getting a physics-based explanation is relatively low here I'd assume, but a computational-based explanation on errors I may have made is more likely.

I'm happy to give more information, for example my code, or the matrices used in the scheme, etc. Thanks in advance!

Here's a link to GIF of time evolution:

[image]

And the part of my code relevant to solving the 1D TDSE:
(pretty much the entire thing except the plotting)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# Define function for norm.
def normf(dxc, uc, ic):
    return sum(dxc * np.square(np.abs(uc[ic, :])))

# Define function for expectation value of position.
def xexpf(dxc, xc, uc, ic):
    return sum(dxc * xc * np.square(np.abs(uc[ic, :])))

# Define function for expectation value of squared position.
def xexpsf(dxc, xc, uc, ic):
    return sum(dxc * np.square(xc) * np.square(np.abs(uc[ic, :])))

# Define function for standard deviation.
def sdaf(xexpc, xexpsc, ic):
    return np.sqrt(xexpsc[ic] - np.square(xexpc[ic]))

# Time t: t0 =< t =< tf. Have N steps at which to evaluate the CN scheme. The
# time interval is dt. decp: variable for plotting to certain number of decimal
# places.
t0 = 0
tf = 20
N = 200
dt = tf / N
t = np.linspace(t0, tf, num = N + 1, endpoint = True)
decp = str(dt)[::-1].find('.')

# Initialise array for filling with norm values at each time step.
norm = np.zeros(len(t))

# Initialise array for expectation value of position.
xexp = np.zeros(len(t))

# Initialise array for expectation value of squared position.
xexps = np.zeros(len(t))

# Initialise array for alternate standard deviation.
sda = np.zeros(len(t))

# Position x: -a =< x =< a. M is an even number. There are M + 1 total discrete
# positions, for the points to be symmetric and centred at x = 0.
a = 100
M = 1200
dx = (2 * a) / M
x = np.linspace(-a, a, num = M + 1, endpoint = True)

# The gaussian function u diffuses over time. sd sets the width of gaussian. u0
# is the initial gaussian at t0.
sd = 1
var = np.power(sd, 2)
mu = 0
u0 = np.sqrt(1 / np.sqrt(np.pi * var)) * np.exp(-np.power(x - mu, 2) / (2 * \
                                                                        var))
u = np.zeros([len(t), len(x)], dtype = 'complex_')
u[0, :] = u0

# Normalise u.
u[0, :] = u[0, :] / np.sqrt(normf(dx, u, 0))

# Set coefficients of CN scheme.
alpha = dt * -1j / (4 * np.power(dx, 2))
beta = dt * 1j / (4 * np.power(dx, 2))

# Tridiagonal matrices Al and AR. Al to be solved using Thomas algorithm.
Al = np.zeros([len(x), len(x)], dtype = 'complex_')

for i in range (0, M):
       Al[i + 1, i] = alpha
       Al[i, i] = 1 - (2 * alpha)
       Al[i, i + 1] = alpha

# Corner elements for BC's.
Al[M, M], Al[0, 0] = 1 - alpha, 1 - alpha

Ar = np.zeros([len(x), len(x)], dtype = 'complex_')

for i in range (0, M):
       Ar[i + 1, i] = beta
       Ar[i, i] = 1 - (2 * beta)
       Ar[i, i + 1] = beta

# Corner elements for BC's.
Ar[M, M], Ar[0, 0] = 1 - 2*beta, 1 - beta

# Thomas algorithm variables. Following similar naming as in Wiki article.
a = np.diag(Al, -1)
b = np.diag(Al)
c = np.diag(Al, 1)

NT = len(b)

cp = np.zeros(NT - 1, dtype = 'complex_')

for n in range(0, NT - 1):
    if n == 0:
        cp[n] = c[n] / b[n]
    else:
        cp[n] = c[n] / (b[n] - (a[n - 1] * cp[n - 1]))

d = np.zeros(NT, dtype = 'complex_')

dp = np.zeros(NT, dtype = 'complex_')

# Iterate over each time step to solve CN method. Maintain boundary
# conditions. Keep track of standard deviation.
for i in range(0, N):
       # BC's.
       u[i, 0], u[i, M] = 0, 0
       
       # Find RHS.
       d = np.dot(Ar, u[i, :])
       
       for n in range(0, NT):
           if n == 0:
               dp[n] = d[n] / b[n]
           else:
               dp[n] = (d[n] - (a[n - 1] * dp[n - 1])) / (b[n] - (a[n - 1] * \
                                                                  cp[n - 1]))

       nc = NT - 1
       while nc > -1:
           if nc == NT - 1:
               u[i + 1, nc] = dp[nc]
               nc -= 1
           else:
               u[i + 1, nc] = dp[nc] - (cp[nc] * u[i + 1, nc + 1])
               nc -= 1

       norm[i] = normf(dx, u, i)
       xexp[i] = xexpf(dx, x, u, i)
       xexps[i] = xexpsf(dx, x, u, i)
       sda[i] = sdaf(xexp, xexps, i)


# Fill in final norm value.
norm[N] = normf(dx, u, N)

# Fill in final position expectation value.
xexp[N] = xexpf(dx, x, u, N)

# Fill in final squared position expectation value.
xexps[N] = xexpsf(dx, x, u, N)

# Fill in final standard deviation value.
sda[N] = sdaf(xexp, xexps, N)
```

Comment: A more logical place would be scicomp.SE for problems with numerical algorithms and the like, with mathjax support. /// The absolute value looks reasonable, so your concern is about the initially rapid phase dynamic?

Comment: @LutzLehmann ah, thank you for the advice on where to post, I did not know that existed! I agree the probability density looks OK, but yes I don't understand why the central peak for the real part of the wave has that depression growing over time (also I don't know what "rapid phase dynamic" means to be honest!).

Comment: The last was just an impression. The initial state is purely real, but in the animation the phase is radically different from zero, visible imaginary part, real part with negative segments, from the start.

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes, the initial state is a real gaussian, and simulating its time evolution using Schroedinger equation (TDSE), which has imaginary units as a factor for the spacial derivatives. I suppose the negative imaginary part at the start balances. If I think that I'm getting what you're getting at: if the real part's phase were different (more ...centric? or about the mean value?) then the peak would be more typical? But then I'm not sure why its phase is the way it is, where it originates from...

Comment: With "phase"  I mean the angle of the complex value. In the later part of the animation, the real and imaginary components change rather slowly relative to the initial part, thus the suspicion that there is a slow and a fast dynamic, with the fast dynamic quickly running into some kind of slow moving equilibrium.

Comment: It's simple-minded but would this arise from interval choices? I think I've chosen appropriately, and the solution itself seems stable otherwise...  and I have seen elsewhere that the time step may need to be made negative to counter-act negative sign in SE. Applying -dt results in some different behaviour, of which it seems the the phase is less dynamic (more consistent)?

Comment: Hyperbolic PDE like `u_t=F(u,u_x,u_xx)` have the difficulty that the right side is not Lipschitz, differentiation is unbounded. In the best case all eigenvalues of the occurring Jacobians have non-positive real parts so that the forward dynamic is stable. Then at least implicit methods can give useful numerical approximations, explicit methods require ridiculously small time steps. In the opposite case, for instance by reversing the time arrow, all methods will give expanding unstable results